# Run-Time Error Regarding Set Button Tint List

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, nosuchmethoderror

Attempting to set the colour(s) of a radio button. I get no errors in the code and am able to run the app on various devices with no issues (API => 22), however, on certain devices (API 16) the app crashes and I am left with the following debug error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.CompoundButton.setButtonTintList

I can't see any obvious issues with the section of code (attached below) that would be effected by API 16. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
            CompoundButton t;

            t = new CheckBox(context);

            int[][] states = new int[][] {
                    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
                    new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
                    new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
                    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
            };

            int[] colors = new int[] {
                    Color.BLACK,
                    Color.RED,
                    Color.GREEN,
                    Color.BLUE
            };

            ColorStateList c = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
            t.setButtonTintList(c);
```

Comment: Yes , on lower API's(API<21) this method  is not available , so change your code accordingly .... it will work

Comment: Thanks looking into it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the native method [`setButtonTintList(ColorStateList)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setButtonTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) for API levels inferior than 21. You should use this compatibility method [`setButtonTintList(CompoundButton, ColorStateList)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CompoundButtonCompat.html#setButtonTintList(android.widget.CompoundButton,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)) for older APIs. Read the documentation to understand how to use [Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, understand the issue a lot better now.